# Why is git pushing to two branches in this git push?

Tags: git, version-control

What would possibly cause a 'git push' to try and commit to two branches? I have my own branch I'm working on, which is on the shared repo... and a master branch. Right now I just wanted to push to my personal branch which went through just fine, but it also tried to push to master and got rejected. Looked something like this:

```
foo$ git push
Counting objects: 38, done.
Delta compression using 2 threads.
Compressing objects: 100% (19/19), done.
Writing objects: 100% (21/21), 9.73 KiB, done.
Total 21 (delta 14), reused 0 (delta 0)
To ssh://example.com/project.git
   8184634..86b621e  mybranch -> mybranch
 ! [rejected]        master -> master (non-fast forward)
error: failed to push some refs to 'ssh://example.com/project.git'
```

My config looks like this:

```
remote.origin.url=ssh://example.com/project.git
remote.origin.fetch=+refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/origin/*
branch.master.remote=origin
branch.master.merge=refs/heads/master
branch.mybranch.remote=origin
branch.mybranch.merge=refs/heads/mybranch
```

Esko notes that it's pushing to both because they're in my config. What if I want to push to both, just not simultaneously? When I have mybranch checked out and I git push, I clearly mean to push mybranch and not master. There's times when I'll checkout master, edit code, and want to commit/push that also. Is there a way for both to co-exist?

Answer (score 28, accepted):

When using `git push` without any arguments, it will push all local branches that have a corresponding remote branch with the same name. Since your local repository has branches `master`and `mybranch`, and also the remote repository has branches `master`and `mybranch`, then Git will push both of them.

If you want to push only one branch, you can say to Git explicitly that which branch you want to push: `git push origin mybranch`

If you want to push master, you can fix that error by first pulling from master. Git complains about the merge being non-fast forward, because somebody else has pushed a commit to master since the last time that you pulled from master.

Comment: What if I do want to push both of them, just not at the same time? There's times I will want to push just mybranch, and there's times when I'll merge mybranch into master and want to push master. What does one do in that case?

Comment: You can always explicitly name the branch that you want to push, using the form "git push <repository> <branch>". See http://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-push.html

Comment: Newer versions of git allow you to specify this behavior.

Comment: Not true. Git pushes both branches because 'push matching' (push those branches which are present on both local side, and on remote you push to) is the default behavior.

Comment: This strikes me as odd, but I guess it explains the behavior I'm seeing (make change on one branch, commit it, `git push`, get `[rejected]` and `failed to push some refs` on two other branches while Git’s at it).

Comment: `git config --global push.default current` is probably what the original questioner wanted, and certainly what I do.

Answer (score 3):

If you want to push only current branch, you can use "git push origin HEAD", or perhaps even "git push HEAD" (with modern git).

The default behavior if no refspec for ***push*** (you have defined refspec for *fetch* in your config, but not for *push*) is to push **matching** refs. From [git-push(1)](http://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-push.html):

> git push [...] [*<repository>* *<refspec>*...]
>
> *<refspec>*...
>
> > The special refspec : (or +:  to  allow  non-fast  forward  updates)
> >            directs  git  to  push  "matching"  branches:  for every branch that
> >            exists on the local side, the remote side is updated if a branch  of
> >            the same name already exists on the remote side. This is the **default
> >            operation mode** if no explicit refspec is found (that is neither on
> >            the command line nor ...

Comment: When I run "git push" with a new(er) git (say 1.6.3.1), I get a huge warning, saying that I should set push.default or the repository should configure push refspecs.

I can't for the life of me figure out how to do the second thing. Google hasn't been helpful. (I would like to configure the reository, because the potential push'ers to my repositories will be confused/annoyed with the big fat warning, and I don't want them to have to configure anything after "git clone ...")

Comment: You configure (set up) remote.<remotename>.push, where <remotename> would be probably in your case 'origin', and <refspec> to use for mirror sync push to bare repository would be "+refs/heads/*:refs/heads/*" (and the same for tags)